# Installing GCC?

Tags: linux, bash, gcc, installation

I am trying to install GCC (most importantly, the `g++` compiler) on an Ubuntu machine where I don't have 1) `sudo` permissions or 2) `apt` access (any `apt` command gives the error `Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)`).

I was able to successfully `make` the uncompressed archive that I downloaded from an [official GNU GCC mirror site](https://bigsearcher.com/mirrors/gcc/releases/gcc-12.2.0/), but `make install` failed with the following error:

```bash
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/libexec’: Permission denied
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'install' failed
```

Any ideas for how to get a copy of `g++` 6.0 or higher? Is there a pre-compiled binary I can download from anywhere?. I also don't have a user interface (this is a remote machine I am SSHing into), so a direct link to a file would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before building from source, [configure it](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) to use a custom prefix (e.g. `./configure --prefix=/some/path/you/can/write/to`).

Comment: I would prefer `$HOME/.local` or `$HOME/local`, but yep.